# How to show TextView in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview, imagebutton

i have a layout made in xml for an android app. The last textview it is not shown. why? what can i do? i try setting the linearlayout with height : fill_parent, wrap_content and match_parent: 
this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/sfondo">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/back1" android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:background="@null" android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/logoTC"
            android:src="@drawable/trovachiavi_contatti" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        </ImageView>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/infoButton"
            android:background="@null" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:src="@drawable/info_mini"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layoutGif1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <spazio.digitale.com.GIFView
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="220dp" android:id="@+id/GIFMulti"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"></spazio.digitale.com.GIFView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/testoAiuto"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:layout_marginTop="-210dp"></TextView>
    <ImageButton android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/avvia_cerca"></ImageButton>
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/testoRicercaMulti"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you see on the screen? Oh, fill_parent is the deprecated version of match_parent btw, they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: emulator is very bad! i try on galaxy S II, and at the end of screen there is a rectangular part that hide my textview..

Comment: Hm, so your view fills the entire screen and then some? Have you tried placing the whole thing inside a ScrollView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your layout just isn't fitting. Wrap your views in a ScrollView, for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/sfondo">

   ...

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/testoRicercaMulti"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    </TextView>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

your layout doesn't fit on your screen. wrap your main LinearLayout inside a ScrollView.